# Split strings into utterances and assign same-speaker utterances to columns in dataframe

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have multi-party conversations in strings like this:

```
convers <- "Peter: Hiya Mary: Hi. How w'z your weekend. Peter: a::hh still got a headache. An' you (.) party a lot? Mary: nuh, you know my kid's sick 'n stuff Peter: yeah i know that's=erm al hamshi: hey guys how's it goin'? Peter: Great! Mary: where've you BEn last week al hamshi: ah y' know, camping with my girl friend."
```

I also have a vector with the speakers' names:

```
speakers <- c("Peter", "Mary", "al hamshi")
```

I'd like to create a dataframe with the utterances by each individual speaker in a separate column. I can only do this task in a piecemeal fashion, by addressing each speaker specifically using the indices in `speakers`, and then combine the separate results in a list but what I'd really like to have is a *dataframe* with separate columns for each speaker:

```
Peter <- str_extract_all(convers, paste0("(?<=", speakers[1],":\\s).*?(?=\\s*(?:", paste(speakers, collapse="|"),"):|\\z)"))
Mary <- str_extract_all(convers, paste0("(?<=", speakers[2],":\\s).*?(?=\\s*(?:", paste(speakers, collapse="|"),"):|\\z)"))
al_hamshi <- str_extract_all(convers, paste0("(?<=", speakers[3],":\\s).*?(?=\\s*(?:", paste(speakers, collapse="|"),"):|\\z)"))

df <- list(
  Peter = Peter, Mary = Mary , al_hamshi = al_hamshi
)
df
$Peter
$Peter[[1]]
[1] "Hiya"                                                 "a::hh still got a headache. An' you (.) party a lot?"
[3] "yeah i know that's=erm"                               "Great!"                                              


$Mary
$Mary[[1]]
[1] "Hi. How w'z your weekend."            "nuh, you know my kid's sick 'n stuff" "where've you BEn last week"          


$al_hamshi
$al_hamshi[[1]]
[1] "hey guys how's it goin'?"                 "ah y' know, camping with my girl friend."
```

How can I extract the same-speaker utterances not one by one but *in one go* and how can the results be assigned not to a list but a *dataframe*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a bit of pre-processing, and assuming the names exactly match the speakers in the conversation text, you can do:

```
# Pattern to use to insert new lines in string
pattern <- paste0("(", paste0(speakers, ":", collapse = "|"), ")")

# Split string by newlines
split_conv <- strsplit(gsub(pattern, "\n\\1", convers), "\n")[[1]][-1]

# Capture speaker and text into data frame
dat <- strcapture("(.*?):(.*)", split_conv, data.frame(speaker = character(), text = character()))
```

Which gives:

```
    speaker                                                   text
1     Peter                                                  Hiya 
2      Mary                             Hi. How w'z your weekend. 
3     Peter  a::hh still got a headache. An' you (.) party a lot? 
4      Mary                  nuh, you know my kid's sick 'n stuff 
5     Peter                                yeah i know that's=erm 
6 al hamshi                              hey guys how's it goin'? 
7     Peter                                                Great! 
8      Mary                            where've you BEn last week 
9 al hamshi               ah y' know, camping with my girl friend.
```

To get each speaker into their own column:

```
# Count lines by speaker
dat$cnt <- with(dat, ave(speaker, speaker, FUN = seq_along))

# Reshape and rename
dat <- reshape(dat, idvar = "cnt", timevar = "speaker", direction = "wide")
names(dat) <- sub("text\\.", "", names(dat))

  cnt                                                  Peter                                   Mary                                 al hamshi
1   1                                                  Hiya              Hi. How w'z your weekend.                  hey guys how's it goin'? 
3   2  a::hh still got a headache. An' you (.) party a lot?   nuh, you know my kid's sick 'n stuff   ah y' know, camping with my girl friend.
5   3                                yeah i know that's=erm             where've you BEn last week                                       <NA>
7   4                                                Great!                                    <NA>                                      <NA>
```

If new lines already exist in your text, choose another character that doesn't exist to do use to split the string.

Comment: There's an error: `dat$cnt <- with(dat, ave(speaker, speaker, FUN = seq_along))
Warning messages:
1: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1:2) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
2: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1:3) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
3: In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = 1:4) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: I'm guessing you're still using R version 3.x.x so strings are converted to factors by default.  Edit the above code to `data.frame(speaker = character(), text = character(), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)` or update to R 4.0.x.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `:\\s` to each `speakers`, as you are also doing, then make a `gregexpr` finding the position where a speaker starts. Extract this using `regmatches` and remove the previously added `:\\s` to get the speaker. Make again a `regmatches` but with `invert` giving the sentences. With `spilt` the sentences are grouped to the speaker. To bring this to the desired `data.frame` you have to add `NA` to have the same length for all speakes, done her with `[` inside `lapply`:

```
x <- gregexpr(paste0(speakers, ":\\s", collapse="|"), convers)
y <- sub(":\\s$", "", regmatches(convers, x)[[1]])
z <- trimws(regmatches(convers, x, TRUE)[[1]][-1])
tt <- split(z, y)
do.call(data.frame, lapply(tt, "[", seq_len(max(lengths(tt)))))
#                                 al.hamshi                                 Mary                                                Peter
#1                 hey guys how's it goin'?            Hi. How w'z your weekend.                                                 Hiya
#2 ah y' know, camping with my girl friend. nuh, you know my kid's sick 'n stuff a::hh still got a headache. An' you (.) party a lot?
#3                                     <NA>           where've you BEn last week                               yeah i know that's=erm
#4                                     <NA>                                 <NA>                                               Great!
```

Comment: Really cool. I don't get this part though: `"["`inside the `lapply`expression. What does it mean/do?

Comment: It's only to fill up with `NA` if there are not so many lines for that Person. But I made an update of the process.